Using multiple ASP.NET Core MVC models in a view
In my ASP.NET Core MVC app, I have a registration page, it uses a model class. I am using Dapper for database connectivity. The form works well, no issues. I need to add another model so that I can display some more information about the product in the sidebar.
@model Core.Library.Models.Lead; 
...............

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

Approach #1
In the controller, I am passing the result in the view like below.
var Result = _db.Query<BoatBasic>(

Boats.GetBasicSummaryWithEngine(BoatId, SourceWebsite)).ToList();
return View(Result);

But when I try to iterate, I get an error:
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // ...
}


Error CS1579
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Lead' because 'Lead' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Approach #2
Then I tried to pass through through ViewBag:
ViewBag.BoatBasic = _db.Query<BoatBasic>(

Boats.GetBasicSummaryWithEngine(BoatId, SourceWebsite)).ToList();
And I am using lambda expression to iterate over it:
@BoatBasic.ForEach(x =>
{
     var tmpMonthNameYear = x.MonthNameYear;
});


Error CS1977
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Approach #3
I have tried composite model as suggested in different question. But that also didn't work.
string BoatId = ViewBag.BoatId;
CompositeModel compositeModel = new CompositeModel
{
    lead = new Core.Library.Models.Lead(),
    boatBasic = _db.Query<BoatBasic>(Boats.GetBasicSummaryWithEngine(BoatId, SourceWebsite)).ToList()
};
return View(compositeModel);
    
public class CompositeModel
{
    public Lead lead;
    public List<BoatBasic> boatBasic;
}

In the view:
@foreach (var item in Model.boatBasic)
{
    // ...
    <h5 class="text-muted">Model:</h5>
    <p style="margin-left: 10px;">@item.Model</p>
    // ...
}


Error CS1061
'Lead' does not contain a definition for 'boatBasic' and no accessible extension method 'boatBasic' accepting a first argument of type 'Lead' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am stuck on how to proceed. I have explored many solutions on this website, but somehow I'm not able to crack it. Please advise.

Approach #3 would be the way to go - but you need to do two things:
#1: you need to use properties (not class fields) for your values in CompositeModel:
public class CompositeModel
{
    public Lead lead { get; set; }
    public List<BoatBasic> boatBasic { get; set; }
}

#2: you need to change the view's @model directive to reference that CompositeModel:
@model Core.Library.Models.CompositeModel; 


Yes Marc, I did try this... But it gives the error.
CS1061 'CompositeModel' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no accessible extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'CompositeModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`
@model Core.Library.Models.CompositeModel;
public class CompositeModel
{
public Lead lead { get; set; }
public List boatBasic { get; set; }
}
`

@RajivRanjan: well, you probably need to reference Model.lead.FirstName (or asp-for="lead.FirstName") to get to that value .....

Thanks a lot Marc, I didnot know of this approach. really appreciate it.

Thanks Mark, it led me to explore the solution. This is what I did, instead of property Lead I have extended CompositeModel from the Lead. That did the trick. I do not why this worked not the previous one.
public class CompositeModel : Lead
{
public List<BoatBasic> boatBasic { get; set; }
}


CompositeModel compositeModel = new CompositeModel
{
boatBasic = _db.Query<BoatBasic>(
Library.Web.Boats.GetBasicSummaryWithEngine(BoatId, SourceWebsite)).ToList()
};
return View(compositeModel);

Thank you for all the support. Please feel free to add any better ways to handle this.
